# Rails logo disappearing on new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, user-interface

I'm building a rails app that has a form with a new action in the controller.

I have a basic nav template that I have in my application.html.erb

```
<a class="brand" href="index.html">
<img src="assets/logo.png" height="30" alt="logo" /></a>
```

When I click on an action that renders an index action the logo stays put.  But when I click on a new action the logo disappears.

Any idea why this is happening?  I'm ok at rails but I am horrible at design/ui/ux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a front-end issue, can i see your a:visited {css} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Sprockets then your way is a little bit wrong. You should use `image_tag` helper to show images

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png", height: 30, alt: 'logo' %>
```

It should prevent it from disapearing and also it should always set proper path to your image (as sprockets can add some extra data (hash) to this path).